# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

When I run the following code in Python 3.3:

```
import urllib
tempfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://yahoo.com")
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I did this too to verify:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're running it in Python 3?

Comment: Yes I am sure!!, I've tried running it on 3.2 and 3.4 as well. No Luck :(

Comment: Maybe try `import urllib.request` directly? It [doesn't appear](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7ff62415e426/Lib/urllib/__init__.py) that `urllib` will pull in its sub-modules itself with 3.3.x.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks man! you should have posted that as answer so i could it accept it ;)

Comment: This error also appears when you have a file in the same directory named as a standard module. Annoying but true. Be careful!

Comment: Had the same issue just now. When first importing urllib, dir(urllib) does not show 'request'. The weird thing is, when I go to help() >> modules >> quit >> dir(urllib), the 'request' method shows up.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The `urllib` module has been split into parts and renamed in Python 3 to `urllib.request`, `urllib.parse`, and `urllib.error`.

---

Import `urllib.request` instead of `urllib`.

```
import urllib.request
```

Comment: I've made sure and tried it on other 3.x versions as well, also added a picture in the question to make sure that there is urllib module. still no luck :3

Comment: For some reason my code works with `import urllib` on one machine, while the other does require `import urrlib.request`.. both run 3.4.2. Anyway, this worked wonders!

Comment: @Joost, Check the version you're using by run `python -V`. or put following line into the script and run it: `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: what a twisted name for a module, when another module 'urllib' also exists. I guess it is for some backwards compatibility, but still..

Comment: i tried with urllib.request, the error changed to "No module named request"

Comment: @rodrigorf, Maybe you're using Python 2.x. Or check whether there's `urllib.py` in the working directory; that will prevent import of standard library `urllib`. In such case, rename `urllib.py` (remove `urllib.pyc` if there is one)

Comment: Thanks @falsetru, the problem was exactly the version of Heroku. I forced the runtime version on Heroku to use 3.4.3. Its working now.

Comment: Why does this happen?

Comment: @johan, because importing a packge does not automatically import its submodule. (some does, like os.path ...)

Comment: Although this works, it may be better to explain why `import urllib` does not work so that the reader gains more understanding of this problem.

Comment: @jdhao, I added explanation. Thank you for feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, I noticed some IDE-depending behavior.

Both Spyder and PyCharm use the same interpreter on my machine : in PyCharm I need to do

> import urllib.request

while in Spyder,

> import urllib

does fine

Comment: Even more weird is running in the interpreter. import urllib; urllib.request will give you the expected AttributeError, but then run urllib.request again, and it's there! It seems that in the interpreter, after throwing an AttributeError, it implicitly imports all the submodules anyway. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

If this is on PyCharm, as was mine, make sure your file name isn't urllib.py.

Answer (score 0):

- In visual code , u have to write import urllib.request instead of just import urllib.
- Also, whenever errors such as **module x has no attribute y occurs**, it's because you have named the current file same as the package you are trying to import.
- So, the way import in python works is that it first searches the current dir, and if it finds the module/package 'x' u were looking for , it assumes that it has found the target file, and searches for 'y'. And since u haven't defined 'y', the aforementioned error occurs.