# Python, when import from module cmd I haven't all attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

When I import module urllib in cmd I have only magic fuctions but when I import this module from Spyder I have all attribute.

I'm adding printscreen of this.

Why can not I import all attribute?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import all attributes of a module into the global namespace use `from module import *`.

While `dir()` simply lists the attributes of the global namespace, `dir(module)` lists the ones in the scope of the specific module.

Anyway, when you `import urllib` you can still reach all attributes if you specify the module name, e.g. `urllib.request`.

Comment: But in cmd when I import urllib and I'm trying to use urllib.request I have an AttributeError -> no attribute 'request' 
When I'm using spider every thing is ok

Comment: That is indeed the case. Simply use `import urllib.request` in your IDLE. For further reading check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278993/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-request.